# ggplot2 scale_x_continuous gives non-numeric argument error

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is happening. In brief the following code works fine:

```
PLOT<-ggsurvplot(
  flysurv,
  data = FlyData,
  size = 1,                 
  palette = c(iwanthue(20)),       
  conf.int = TRUE,          
  legend.labs = c(levels(Gtype)))
  ggtheme = theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 17),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 13),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14)
        )
PLOT
```

But I am trying to redefine the axis ticks using scale_x_continuous to give the x-axis ticks from 0-120 every 24. Example:

```
PLOT + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,24))
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error in PLOT + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 120, 24)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.ggsurv", "+.gg") for "+"
```

Was just following a guide and they say "this should work" and it doesn't, and I haven't found a question on StackOverflow that applies here except someone with a simple "hanging +" typo...
Happy for extra tips here. Like... can I just directly put this into the ggplot main plot code so it isn't entered as this awkward add-on afterwards? Aesthetically I like the entire plot code to be wrapped in the same parentheses...

Comment: Can you run the following for your dataset to check which type of data do you have in your columns, I suspect that the data you have may not be numeric: str(data)

Comment: Which packages have you in use? And where is FlyData from? Could you provide the data?

Comment: Try adding that scale to `P$plot` instead ( https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html#value )

Comment: > str(FlyData)
tibble [60 × 9] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Genotype                                                                   : chr [1:60] ...
 $ Time dead                                                                  : num [1:60] ... 

% Time dead is the x-axis. The y-axis is proportion data based on the number alive/dead at a given time (per ggsurvplot and the survfit function).

As mentioned, the code works fine, I the data informing the x-axis are fine. I just can't seem to change the x-axis ticks/distribution.

Comment: @margusl thanks for the interest. Not sure what you mean though? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html#value), `ggsurvplot()` return value is not a ggplot object. Though there's a `$plot` attribute and we can modify that instead:

```r
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
P <- survminer::ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

P + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,101))
#> Warning: Incompatible methods ("+.ggsurv", "+.gg") for "+"
#> Error in P + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, 101)): non-numeric argument to binary operator
# ... fails, because P is not a ggplot object:
class(P)
#> [1] "ggsurvplot" "ggsurv"     "list"

# but P$plot is:
class(P$plot)
#> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"

# so we'll add scale_x_continuous() to P$plot instead:
P$plot <- P$plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,101))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.

P
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

(while you do have a typo that quite neatly creates a new `ggtheme` object, it's not causing that error you see and I can't quite agree with closing votes; though you should notice you are not getting bw theme and still have old sizes for text and title )

Comment: That was it! Aha... Thank you! Yes I was playing around with placing theme() and such before after finding the stackoverflow on the hanging + typo, but as you mention, it wasn't the issue.

Thank you again! I would never have thought to check if ggsurvplot() was not producing a ggplot object. It's got ggplot in the name. Seemed like a ggplot!